# Scapy graphical dump of custom protocols

Tags: python, scapy, pyx

I defined the following packet:

```
p = IP()/TCP()/Unique()
```

where Unique is a new layer:

```
class Unique(Packet):
name = "Unique"
fields_desc=[ IntField("a", 0),
         IntField("b", 0),
         IntField("c", 0)]
```

I want to make a graphical PDF dump of *p* but If I use the command

```
p.pdfdump(test.pdf)
```

in the resulting .pdf file the Unique layer is not decoded and therefore it is represented just as Raw.
How can I draw a custom layer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `rebuild` input parameter of `pdfdump` method. I don't know why (because lack of documentation on source code) but if you set `rebuild=0`, your custom protocol details will appear in output. For example:

```
p.pdfdump('test.pdf', rebuild=0)
```